# Ejecutar codigo javascript dentro de un script llamado con ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Necesito mostrar una alerta y detener la ejecucion del script cuando el usuario de clic en el boton de aceptar cuando no selecciona ninguna semana para pagar, esta es la función ajax:

```
$('#sub').click( function() {         
  $("#update").submit(function(e){
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "files/hoursToPay.php",
          type: "POST",
          data:  formData,
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(data){
              alert("Horas pagadas");
          },
          error: function(data){
              console.log(data)
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Dentro del script hoursToPay:

```
<?php

// Si seleccionó al menos una semana
if (isset($_POST['hours'])):
    //Codigo para pagar semanas
else:
    echo '<script>alert("Selecciona al menos una semana"); 
    return false;</script>';
endif;
?>
```

El problema es que el codigo javascript que esta dentro del script no funciona, hay alguna manera de hacerlo funcionar?, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Y por qué dejar que el usuario haga clic en el botón si el formulario no está debidamente cumplimentado?

La solución que propongo es muy simple:

- El botón enviar estará desactivado mientras que el input requerido no tenga datos
- Para controlar eso escucharemos los eventos `change`, `paste` y `keyup` en ese input:

```js
$(function() {
  /*Creamos referencias a los elementos*/
  var $btnEnviar = $("#btnEnviar");
  var $ibxSemana = $("#ibxSemana");

  /*Variable que se posteará*/
  var $postVal = "";

  /*De entrada desactivamos el botón*/
  $btnEnviar.prop("disabled", true);

  /*Aquí escuchamos los cambios en el input*/
  $ibxSemana.on("change paste keyup", function() {
    /*Recogemos el valor del input*/
    $postVal = $.trim($(this).val());
    
    /*Determinamos si está o no vacío para activar o no el botón*/
    var btnDisabled = ($postVal == "") ? true : false;

    /*Cambiamos o  no  el estado del botón según el valor de btnDisabled*/
    $btnEnviar.prop("disabled", btnDisabled);

  });

  /*
   *Se ejecutará al hacer clic en el botón
   *aquí pones tu llamada Ajax
   */
  $btnEnviar.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Aquí la petición Ajax, usando la variable $postVal cuyo valor actual es ${$postVal}`);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="tuarchivo.php" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="usuario">Semana:
<input id="ibxSemana" type="text" name="semana" required /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button id="btnEnviar" type="submit" name="enviar">Enviar</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok esa tmb puede ser una opción, lo unico que hice fue agregar este codigo: `$("input:checkbox").on(\'change\', function() {
        $(\'#sub\').prop("disabled", !this.checked);
      }).trigger(\'change\');`

Dado que son puros checkboxes, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder ejecutar el alert con AJAX no es necesario convocar a un archivo PHP, puedes intentar

```
$('#sub').click( function() {         
  $("#update").submit(function(e){
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  var horasPagadas = variableHTML //-----
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   url: "files/hoursToPay.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  formData,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(horasPagadas){
          alert("Horas pagadas" . horasPagadas );
      },
      error: function(data){
          console.log(data)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Y en el caso de que el usuario **no** seleccione nada como interrumpo la ejecución del script?